# How to build dependent projects without referencing them?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In my solution, rather than referencing DLL's for certain libraries, those projects have been included in my solution:

[image]

Rather than having to include the projects part of the solution, is it possible to either have them part of the [build definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181716(v=vs.120).aspx), or perhaps as pre-build event command line:

[image]

**How do I include projects that need to be built for my solution without actually having them loaded in the solution?**

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use references? Anyway yes you could use a prebuild event issueing multiple msbuild statements to build each projetc.

Comment: @stijn the reason is because those projects are under constant development from other solutions

Comment: @stijn This is quite common when using a plugin architecture or something like MEF

Comment: @MeggieLuski Have you tried looking at the configuration manager? See if the projects are set to build in there.

Comment: yes they are set to build, but why does that matter?

Comment: @DavidG sure but if it would be for using MEF those projects aren't really referenced and build order wouldn't matter

Comment: How about NuGet packages?

Answer (score 3):

I have all project in same solution that are not referenced and i build them by putting following command in pre-build event of startup project

"$(DevEnvDir)devenv" "$(SolutionDir)SolutionName.sln" /Rebuild $(ConfigurationName) /project "$(SolutionDir)ProjectFolder\ProjectFile.csproj"

Corrected!

"$(DevEnvDir)devenv" "$(SolutionPath)" /Rebuild $(ConfigurationName) /project "$(SolutionDir)YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER\PROJECT_FILE.csproj"

Comment: This is the right answer, though needs an small modification: "$(DevEnvDir)devenv" "$(SolutionPath)" /Rebuild $(ConfigurationName) /project "$(SolutionDir)YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER\PROJECT_FILE.csproj"

Answer (score 2):

You can work in 2 ways. You reference either other projects, or dlls in your project. And you can combine both. If you don't want some projects being build in the solution as not being part of the solution, you must pre-build them and point references to the output of the compilation process. And if you want them to be part of the solution but not compile, use Build Configuration Manager. You can use that to mark, which projects get built under that configuration, and which don't get built.

If you have a large solution, it is better to set output to an arbitrary *bin* or *lib* folder and reference from there as well. Make sure to set project build order in this case.

For a small solution, project reference will work fine. In this case, build order will establish itself.

The difference is performance - in case #1 - dll reference allows you to build single project. In case #2, building a single project will trigger chain of project compilations. In this case, you just wait longer each time. In a large solution this is detrimental for developers.

And last thing, if you have some DLLs that are not referenced but are used in your app by, lets say being loaded via reflection, you can use *pre build* or *post build* events to copy these into `$(TargetDir)`

Comment: "you must pre-build them and point references to the output of the compilation process. " ---- how do i do this?

Comment: This question puts me "against the wall" - you build them as part of another solution, for example. Then, you should have a `bin` folder where you store them permanently. Then you go to `project-add reference-browse`. Select your dll and add reference

Comment: i totally relate to "against the wall" - reality is not as easy as simply subscribing to a nuget feed, if you recommend to build them as part of another solution, please keep in mind that these referenced projects are under constant development, so how do i force another solution to be built (as you suggest) prior to building the current solution?

Comment: Do you have control of that "other" solution?

Comment: you are suggesting to create another solution with the needed projects, correct?

Comment: If you can get latest version and build - yes. If you can't, the people who work on it should include an action to distribute dlls on network and you can run batch to grab it from there. We have code base so large that we build 8 solutions, one after another

Comment: how would i instruct my solution to build another solution prior to building itself?

Comment: there are ways to deal with it. First, you can have these projects in the same solution only you need to create different configurations. In one config you build only those dependency projects. And in other config you build only dependent projects. Or, you in fact can build multiple solutions sequentially. Create batch file and use `devenv rebuild 'configname|AnyCpu' . . .. .`.

Comment: Check this 
`if exist "%~dp0\solution1.log" DEL /F "%~dp0\solution1.log"
echo Building solution1.sln ...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" solution1.sln /Rebuild "Debug|AnyCpu" /Out solution1.log
notepad "%~dp0\solution1.log"
pause

if exist "%~dp0\solution2.log" DEL /F "%~dp0\solution2.log"
echo solution2.sln ...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" solution2.sln /Rebuild "Debug|AnyCpu" /Out solution2.log
notepad "%~dp0\solution2.log"
pause`

Comment: so i would be able to do this both for local builds and tfs builds?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137493/discussion-between-meggie-luski-and-t-s).

Comment: The way your solution builds and what projects are built is regulated by Build Configuration settings. I am not 100% sure of full capability of TFS but I know that you point solution and configuration, i.e. `Release|AnyCpu`. I am sure you can do it [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/14de89a3-8df1-43fb-8a1a-c049b655eb4b/building-two-solutions-within-single-tfs-build?forum=tfsbuild]  We're using commercial product called FinalBuilder for release builds. TFS build is just a free add-on to TFS server. And yet, if you know how to modify workflow, you can do a lot with it